# Use of hive in flutter application

Tags: flutter, hive

I am using hive for flutter application,
Is it safe, is it scalable, good to continue with hive or should I use sqlite or any other database for flutter application.

Comment: It has strong built-in encryption of AES-256. Try :https://pub.dev/packages/hive https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/

Answer (score 0):

here are some features of hive :

> Hive is a lightweight and blazing fast key-value database written in pure Dart.
> have 120 points that is full a package can have.
> As per flutter official policy no any package can be deleted once its uploaded on pud.dev.
> Strongly encrypted using AES-256.

so you should definetly go for hive. if you don't have experience in native.